# Creating an app/widget in Android to clear the default values of a certain app

Tags: android, widget

I need to write a code to create an app/widget that will "Clear Defaults" for an app. Instead of going to "Settings->Applications->[The App]->Clear Defaults", the user will click on the app icon (or widget) to clear these default values.

I am new to Android. I just want some help to create and build my first Android app/widget.

Many thanks...

Comment: "An app" being your app? Also, have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I think he means installed apps not his .

Comment: I meant my app, but I realized that I cannot modify other apps like CommonsWare said. All the apps on Play Store redirect to the apps page in Settings in order to clear default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot affect other apps in this fashion. Only the Settings app, or possibly apps written as part of the device firmware, can change the default apps for particular `Intent` constructs.